# Elasticsearch query array field across documents

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to query the array field from elasticsearch. I have an array field that contains one or several node numbers of a gpu that were allocated to a job. Different people may be using the same node at the same time given that some people may be sharing the same gpu node with others. I want get the total number of distinct nodes that were used at a specific time.

Say I have three rows of data which fall in the same time interval. I want to plot a histogram showing that there are three nodes occupied in that period. Can I achieve this on Kibana?

Example :

[3]

[3,4,5]

[4,5]

I am expecting an output of 3 since there were only 3 distinct nodes used.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a combination of a date histogram aggregation along with either a terms aggregation (if the exact number of nodes is important) or a cardinality aggregation (if you can accept some inaccuracy at higher cardinalities).

Full example:

```
# Start with a clean slate
DELETE test-index

# Create the index
PUT test-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "event": {
      "properties": {
        "nodes": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# Index a few events (using the rows from your question)
POST test-index/event/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"timestamp": "2018-06-10T00:00:00Z", "nodes":[3]}
{"index":{}}
{"timestamp": "2018-06-10T00:01:00Z", "nodes":[3,4,5]}
{"index":{}}
{"timestamp": "2018-06-10T00:02:00Z", "nodes":[4,5]}

# STRATEGY 1: Cardinality aggregation (scalable, but potentially inaccurate)
POST test-index/event/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "active_nodes_histo": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "hour"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "active_nodes": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "nodes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# STRATEGY 2: Terms aggregation (exact, but potentially much more expensive)
POST test-index/event/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "active_nodes_histo": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "hour"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "active_nodes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "nodes",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. **Terms vs. cardinality aggregation:** Use the cardinality agg unless you need to know WHICH nodes are in use.  It is significantly more scalable, and until you get into cardinality of 1000s, you likely won't see any inaccuracy.
2. **Date histogram interval:** You can play with the interval such that it's something that makes sense for you.  If you run through the example above, you'll only see one histogram bucket, however if you change `hour` to `minute`, you'll see the histogram build itself out with more data points.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I want.